# What is the correct term for someone who works on/with WordPress?

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

I'm trying to figure out what the best way to describe someone who works with/on WordPress. Some people use WordPresser but that seems a little bit clunky for me. It's easy to say WordPress developer, designer, etc but if you wanted to talk about how to talk about lots of people who work on WordPress what would be the best way for form the correct word?

Example of usage: "he was the best WordPresser of them all" etc.

I've been thinking it might be appropriate to formulate it like you would a person of a specific nationality - i.e. Italian, or whatever. But I'm not sure what would be right, both grammatically and to make sure it doesn't sound clunky.

Comment: Might be a better fit for [WordPress.SE](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/) (though possibly their chat rather than main site).

Comment: @ЯegDwight I am mod at WPSE and suggested to ask here. Definitely not a fit for our site and chat there won't contribute much to it, given there is mostly bunch of non-native speakers hanging out :)

Comment: Please define "with/on WordPress". Do you mean someone who (a) contributes to a website which is set up using WordPress; (b) someone who set up such a website; (c) someone who develops WordPress plugins and the like; (d) someone from WordPress.org who writes the framework itself; (e) something else?

Comment: I would say contributes to WordPress.org, runs a WP business, or develops WordPress Plugins & Themes etc; i.e. someone who dedicates their working life to the use, creation or dissemination of the WordPress CMS.

Comment: Not Constructive. This is all about making upp a new word from a made-up word. Do they use WordPresser? then that's what they use.  Do you have another suggestion? Then try it out and see if it gains traction. Clunkiness is open to lots of feelings and interpretation so will not be constructive (there's no 'right' answer)

Comment: There are lots of different jobs that utilise wordpress and they all require different skills. Calling yourself a wordpresser is like calling yourself a *movie maker* because you work in the movie industry.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I feel that there are multiple factors working against forming an [agent noun](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agent_noun) from *WordPress*:

- camel case
- the *-ss* ending
- lack of distinct function of person (can be developer, designer, user, etc.)
- multiple meanings of *press* outside of the word

*Wordpresser* seems to marginally work because [*presser*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/presser) is a real word and *-er* is one of the few suffixes that feel more or less short and natural here.

*Wordpressman* is another viable option (*businessman*, *congressman*).

However, stepping away from hammering meaning into one word, I think the accurate and non-clunky way to put it would be *WordPress professional*. It distinguishes activity from users, leaves brand part alone and *professional* has no gender/plural/whatever issues.

Comment: you are awesome. Thanks! That's exactly what I need :)

Comment: I would suggest, however, that we keep the term "WordPressionist" for someone who claims to be a WordPress designer or developer, but who actually uses themes bought from Theme Forest or other theme shops.

Comment: I fail to understand why the _-ss_ ending is of any significance to your argument. Could someone explain this, please? - +1, though.

Comment: @Alexander Kosubek I think it's uncommon and makes suffixes, that would work with another ending, feel clunky. As you see existing words mostly append whole word (_-ss -man_) rather than suffix.

Answer (score 3):

As examples in the same domain, I can think of [netizen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netizen), [Wikipedian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_of_Wikipedia), and [internaut](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internaut). `WordPresser` is also my first instinct due to the existence of `presser`, and it gets some hits on google. I find `WordPressian` pretty understandable, and it also gets some uses from google. I think `WordPressant` is okay but don't see it used. I do not like and don't find uses of: `WordPressaut`, `WordPressizen`, `WordPrestizen`.

If you want to go by sound, the people of Cyprus are (I just discovered) called [Cypriots](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyprus). So `WordPriots`? `WordPressiots`?

Answer (score 2):

WordPresseur (or WordPresseuse, although arguably the addition of a feminised variant is sexist).

Answer (score 2):

A Wordpressitarianistician.

Example usage: "He was the best ***Wordpressitarianistician*** of them all"

Though I believe that there is and shouldn't be a title as such, for the same reason that we don't have a title for both developers and users of Doors and openings. "He was the best ***Doorer*** of them all".

Comment: Ah, but we have *doorman*, so perhaps we could have *Wordpressman* or the gender-neutral *Wordpressperson*. ;)

Comment: So doorman is created by adding two words together. WordPresser seems clunky because it's adding an "er" on to the end of the noun. Maybe the "doorman" model is better to follow and two nouns need to be stuck together. (although WordPress is already two nouns/one noun one verb, depending on your perspective; so maybe three nouns would be insane)

Comment: A doorman opens doors for other people, the term doesn't encompass those who design construct or research Door technology. I feel the term **Doorer** is a more inclusive term, as a precursor to the more formal **Dooritarianistician**

Comment: "Wordpressperson" is gender-neutral? - shouldn't it be "Wordpressperchild"

Answer (score 2):

This is secondary to the real question here—I agree with the selected answer—but I have found "WordPressenter" to be a useful term for one who speaks on topics related to WordPress at conferences. </twocents>

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use Wordpressista or Wordpressorian. Occasionally, I've been known to use Wordpressician.

Answer (score 1):

A *WordPressionist* has a nice ring to it.